# Django low-level many-to-many update without query

Tags: database, django

Here's a bit of database golf. Suppose I have an object:

```
class A(models.Model):
     b = models.ManyToManyField(B)
     #Many other fields
```

Now suppose I want to do bulk updates to the field b.

```
some_objects = A.filter(q).values('id','b')
#Populate a map of ids
related_map = {
    some_objects[0]['id']: [1,2],
    some_objects[1]['id']: [1],
    #etc.
}
```

Now what I would want to do is something like this:

```
for (id,related_ids) in related_map.iteritems():
    A.filter(id=id).update(b=related_ids)
```

which raises a FieldError. Of course, I can just do this

```
for (id,related_ids) in related_map.iteritems():
    a = A.objects.get(id=id)
    a.b = related_ids
```

This works, but it seems unnecessary. I've already extracted all the data I need from the database that I need in order to populate related_map. Is there a built-in way to update many-to-many without querying the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the ORM exposes this unless you declare an intermediary model for the relationship.  You should be able to do it with a direct SQL call if you don't need any special behavior like triggering signals.  Something like:

```
field = A._meta.get_field_by_name('b')[0]
tablename = field.m2m_db_table()
column_a_name = field.m2m_column_name()
column_b_name = field.m2m_reverse_name()

from django.db import connection, transaction
cursor = connection.cursor()
for (id, related_ids) in related_map.iteritems():
    for related_id in related_ids:
        cursor.execute("insert into %s (%s, %s) values (%s, %s)", (tablename, column_a_name, column_b_name, id, related_id))
transaction.commit_unless_managed()
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly has the full docs and discussion of transaction control options.

Those field lookups are not part of the documented API, so there's probably a risk of them changing in future versions.